# nRF24 PCB Antenna Choices

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-antenna, nrf24l01

I am trying to create RF module using the nRF24L01P. I am trying to maximize the range while still using a trace antenna. My plan is to combine the simple trace antenna design with the long range antenna design.

#### Short range nRF24 Module

[image: Standard nRF24 Module]

#### Long range nRF24 Module

[image: Long Range nRF24 Module]

My understanding of the long range design is that it uses a rf amplifier to increase the signal power before sending it through the antenna. What I am hoping to do is keep the trace antenna from the first design but then put the amplifier bettween the antenna and nRF24L01P. Is it feasable to replace a typical SMA antenna with a trace antenna in this way?

Here is a copy of my design. Is there anything else I need to be doing to preserve as much of the range as possible while still using a trace antenna? Also is there a particular type of PCB substrate I need to be using or will just a standard substrate work?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you're seeking longer range, and are going to the trouble of using the extra RF amplifier circuitry, why do you want to impair the range by converting back to a lower-efficiency PCB trace antenna?

If you don't like the "rubber ducky" antenna that comes with the higher-power nRF module, even substituting a bent wire -- of the proper length -- will be superior to the PCB trace antenna.

Answer (score 1):

PCB antennas can work.  However their structure/shape determines the impedance.  If the PA output impedance isn't the same as the low power version, then you can not just drop in a squiggly PCB antenna and have good matching.

The inverted F antenna is pretty common on PCBs.  It gives decent range and is easy to match.  FR4 PCB material will work, but its dielectric constant does vary with humidity and temperature.  So it depends on your application and distance you are attempting to acheive.

Also, as a side note, in my experience, it is better/easier to add an LNA on the input to get better sensitivity ( and thus range ).  The high currents of a PA can make side lobes and spurs, which are harder to get through FCC.